# Dynamic selection of number of clusters in clustering

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

**Edit** This question was written with little knowledge of clustering techniques and now in hindsight does not even meet the Standards of Stack Overflow Website, but SO won't let me delete it saying others have Invested time and Energy in this(Valid Point) and if I proceed to delete, I may not be able to ask questions for a while, So I am updating this question to make it relevant in a way that others can learn from this. Still it doesn't strictly comply with SO guidelines as I myself would flag this as too broad, but in it's current state it is of no value, so adding a little value to it is going to be worth the downvotes.

**Updated Conversation topic**
The Issue was to select the optimal number of cluster in a clustering algorithm which would be grouping various shapes which were the input of contour detection on an Image and then a deviation in cluster properties was to be marked as Noise or anomalies, The main point that raised the question at the time was that all datasets were different, the shapes obtained in them different, and the no of shapes would also vary from dataset to dataset. The proper solution to do this would be to go about using DBSCAN(Density based spatial clustering application with Noise) application of which can be find in `scikit-learn` which I was unaware of at the time, that works and now the product is in testing, I just wanted to come back to this and correct this old mistake.

**Old Question**

**Old Title** Dynamic selection of k in kmeans clustering

I have to generate a k-means clustering model in which number of classes are not known in advance, is there a way to automatically determine the value of k based on the Euclidean distance within the clusters.

How I want it to work. Start with a value of k, perform clustering, see if it satisfies threshold criterion and increase or decrease k accordingly. The problem is framework independent and If you have an Idea or implementation in a language other than Python, please share that as well.

I found this while researching the problem https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267752474_Dynamic_Clustering_of_Data_with_Modified_K-Means_Algorithm.
I couldn't find its Implementation.

I am looking for similar ideas to select the best and implement it myself, or an implementation that can be ported to my code.

Edit
The Ideas I am considering right now are:

1. The elbow method
2. X-means clustering

Comment: You're probably looking for "elbows" or "knees" in the data; a nice Python library that implements [the Kneedle method](https://raghavan.usc.edu/papers/kneedle-simplex11.pdf) is [kneed](https://github.com/arvkevi/kneed).

Comment: @mc10 Yes I was also thinking elbows or x means clustering, I am hoping to get more Ideas to compare, sorry I didn't include those in my question.

Answer (score 5):

You can use elbow method. What this method basically do, is it use various values of k (no of clusters) and then calculate distance of each point from its cluster center. After certain number there won;t any major improvement this value you can take for k(no of cluster).

[image]

You can refer for further reading [this](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/finding-optimal-number-clusters-k-means-through-elbow-asanka-perera/) link.

Comment: I am aware of the Elbow method, the problems are, 1. It is going to be automated, selection of k, I won't be there to see where the elbow is formed, theoretically that can be handled by slope of graph and a threshold technique but then 2. The datasets are huge, around 1 billion objects with around 50 parameters each and the value of k is anything from 10-700, so I need to write something that doesn't follow a linear approach to select k.

Comment: for k between 10-700, i suggest to use value at regular interval. For example n+10 or n+20.

Comment: That might work, I was thinking a binary search mechanism to reach a k and check its difference from k-10 and k+10, based on that, if still significant increase, jump forward I think you get the Idea. I am just hoping to find a better mechanism if possible.

Comment: one more suggestion if it helps. You can divide the total range into fix interval. for example if range is 100 and you just want 10 values then the interval will be 10/10 = 10.

Comment: I guess I can do a ruler zoom version of what you are saying, first move by 100's then by 10's then by 1's.

Answer (score 0):

You iterate over the values of K and check your cluster validity using Silhouette Score

Comment: the model is computationally very expensive, and the dataset is very huge, I don't think this would be feasible.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the score of k values of any range. Either you can check silhouette score for each k value or calculate the difference between SSE values for each k values. Where the difference is highest after 0.4 * number of k values will be the elbow point.